# Routing requests to specific regions/VPCs (Geotargeting)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, website, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

We have two VPCs one in US and the other in Europe. Each VPC has a load balancer in public subnets and we run our web application in private subnets. What we want is, if a user visits our website (makes a request to our host/domain) the request gets redirected to European VPC if the user is from Europe region and to US VPC if the user requests from US.

Answer (score 1):

**GеоDNS** is a good solution.

You can route web traffic based on user’s IP address to different servers located at all over the world using **GEO DNS**. AWS Rout 53 has a option LBR which is givings us the same features as GEO DNS. It's a good article on the issue - 
[How to configure GEO DNS feature using AWS Route53](http://www.linuxfunda.com/2014/01/12/how-to-configure-geo-dns-feature-using-aws-route53/)

On the other hand, if your DNS server is not part of Amazon WAS then you have two options:

- move your domain into AWS
- look for free plugin to yor DNS server (for example: if using bind -  [GeoDNS + Bind](http://thelinuxfaq.com/227-how-to-install-and-configure-geodns-bind-in-centos-fedora-rhel))